# How to use AQuery in android to fetch the data from server side?

Tags: android

I want to fetch the data from the server side, before aquery i used Asynctask to fetch the data from server side but as i got the idea of aquery now i want to fetch the data bu using aquery library. My server page simply returns a string but by using aquery i am not getting response it's showing null in result. Please let me know about aquery functionality and provide a link to get more on aquery.

This is the i am using to get data from server...

```
aqu=new AQuery(getApplicationContext());
        aqu.ajax("here goes my url", String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void callback(String url, String html, AjaxStatus status) {
                  Log.d("here you go",html+"////////////////////"+url); 

            }

    });
```

In html variable i am getting null value, as this is supposed to be a proper response but i am not able to get the response.

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial? http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/introduction-to-aquery-android-query/

Comment: Honestly, when checking the code, it seems like it has been dead for few months...

Comment: Then suggest me how to do it by using Aquery librabry? are you really aware about aquery or not?

Comment: Yes i have seen this tutorial , but when i am using this i am not getting response .@michal

Comment: I am very well aware of it, I have tried it several times, but it never really grew to me. There are better libraries to use when fetching data if you don't want to use AsyncTask. Like Retrofit for example.

Comment: Ok i try to use it, would you please tell me what is the problem with Aquery?

Comment: Could be anything really, do you have any stack trace?

Comment: And please provide a link to get more about retrofit, actually i have to use this library in eclipse IDE and thank you so much for your kind response.@michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you. Calling webservice using Aquery..
http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-json-parsing-tutorial-using-aquery/

**Update:**
Make following changes to functions in the tutorial:

```
public void updateCitySpinnerCtrl(String country) {
        //JSON URL
        String url = "http://apps.programmerguru.com/json/getcity.php?country="+ country;
        //Make Asynchronous call using AJAX method
        aq.progress(R.id.progressBar1).ajax(url, **String.class,** this,"jsonCallback");
    }

    public void jsonCallback(String url, **String** **res**, AjaxStatus status) {
        //When JSON is not null
        Log.i("json="+res,"response");
        if (json != null) {
            //write you code here
        } 
}
```

Comment: By using this i can just fetch JSON objecet but my requirement is to fetch a simple string in response.@ketan

Comment: Make following changes to the functions mentioned in tutuorial

Answer (score 0):

first of download aquery jar library and put in android projects libs folder and add as library and call below flow to get response.

```
try {
    AQuery aq = new AQuery(ctx);

    aq.ajax(url, params, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, JSONObject object, AjaxStatus status) {

            int code = status.getCode();

            try {

                if (code == AjaxStatus.NETWORK_ERROR) {

                    response = null;                            
                    return;

                } else if (code == AjaxStatus.TRANSFORM_ERROR) {

                    response = null;                            
                    return;


                } else if (code == 200) {



                }else{


                    return;

                }

                String result = object.toString();
                Log.e("result:", "" + result);
                if (result.equals("")) {


                } else {


                    try {

                        String sres = new String(result.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
                        response = sres;


                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                        Log.e("utf8", "conversion", e);


                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();


                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

    });

}catch (Exception e){

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```